# ¿Convertir una fecha a timestamp?

Tags: php, timestamp

¿Cómo puedo obtener en PHP una fecha en formato de `timestamp`?

```
$fecha = "2015-12-06";

echo TIMESTAMP($fecha);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Puedes usar una de las dos siguientes formas de obtener el `timestamp`:

#### FORMA #1: Estilo estructurado

```
// Usa el método strtotime()
$timestamp = strtotime($fecha);
```

#### FORMA #2: Estilo orientado a objetos

```
// DateTime class.
$date = new DateTime($fecha);
$timestamp = $date->getTimestamp();
```

---

> **NOTA ACERCA DEL RENDIMIENTO:**
>
> El estilo **estructurado** ( método `strtotime()` ) es más eficiente que el estilo orientado a objetos ( clase `DateTime` ).

Puedes ver un interesante benckmark de estas dos formas de obtener el `timestamp` aquí:

 http://en.code-bude.net/2013/12/19/benchmark-strtotime-vs-datetime-vs-gettimestamp-in-php/

---

**Mi respuesta original:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/28406427/4359029

Answer (score 3):

Si quieres guardar el texto en `$fecha` con formato de timestamp, utiliza la función `strtotime()`. Una vez que guardes en una variable el resultado de la función con tu fecha como parámetro, puedes manipularla como cualquier timestamp. Entonces para obtener tu variable fecha con formato de timestamp sería así:

```
$fecha="2015-12-06";
$variableTimestamp=strtotime($fecha);
```

Una vez convertida a `$variableTimestamp`, puedes manipularla como timestamp, como por ejemplo para cambiar el formato de impresión. Ejemplo:

```
echo date("d/m/Y", $variableTimestamp);
//Resultado: 06/12/2015
```